# How do I handle special characters like(#) in OpenSearchServer / Lucene?

Tags: lucene, search-engine

I am using OpenSearchServer (community edition) v1.2.4-rc3 - stable - rev 1474 - build 802. I crawl a C# and C++ programming website. Now when i search for C# or C++ the software strips special characters like #,+. The results are not exact which software returns. How do I handle special characters like(#) in OpenSearchServer / Lucene? Can any one please suggest me idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your indexing strategy to use a custom or semi-custom tokenizer that preserves the special characters you need to represent C# and C++ code terms. You would use this tokenizer both during indexing and during searching.

Off-hand, I would look at **org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard** and **org.apache.lucene.wikipedia.analysis** to get some ideas as how to construct the tokenizer (using a tokenizer (lexical analyzer) generator like JFlex etc. may be called for rather than hand-coding the tokenizer).